# How do I set the return value of a closure function to a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a closure function that uploads and returns data from a web server. The following code will print the value that I want.

```
  loadData1(onCompletion: { (json) in
     print(json)
  })
```

My problem is that I need to set the printed value equal to a variable to use outside of the function. I have tried this:

```
  let x = loadData1(onCompletion: { (json) in
     return json
  })
```

but I receive the warning "Constant 'x' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected" and the value of x is equal to "()". For reference, the type of json is [[String:String]].

Edit:
Currently have this

```
var x = [[String: String]]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData1(onCompletion: { (json) in
        self.x = json
    })
    print(x)
}
```

and it is printing "[]".

Comment: print(x) inside of a closure, after self.x = json

Comment: You need to study up on asynchronous processing.

Comment: @AnastasiaKovaleva How can I access x in a different part of the code? I need to use it in collection view cell.

Comment: Then you'd better display any placeholder data while your json is loading and after initializing x inside callback closure reload your collection view cell with retrieved data.

Comment: @AnastasiaKovaleva I am still unsure how I can access the json data outside of the closure? If I place x in the ui collection cell, it is an unresolved identifier.

Comment: until closure will be executed, variable x have default value (var x = [[String: String]]()) or is unresolved if you not provide default value for it.

Comment: Ah gotcha now. I initialized x outside of the closure so that I could use x in collection view cell. And like you suggested, after setting the value for x, I reloaded the collection view cell. Thanks so much!

Comment: @AnastasiaKovaleva If you want to put that into the answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @jh95 yes, it would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set value of x variable inside of the closure:

```
loadData1(onCompletion: { (json) in
     x = json
})
```

In your approach variable x initialized with a closure, that's why you received a warning.

Until closure will be executed, variable x have default value `var x = [[String: String]]()` 
or remain unresolved if you did not provide default value along with declaration.

Comment: When I do that and try to print(x) outside of the closure, I receive the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'x'"

Comment: @jh95 You need to declare and initialize the variable before using it, for example `var x =  [[String: String]]()`

Comment: @jh95 That's right, because variable x is not initialized until API call returns some data i.e. closure will be called . Since your closure will be called asynchronously, variable x will be initialized only after closure body execution.

Comment: If you initialize variable x initially, print(x) outside of the closure will display empty array of dictionaries.

Comment: @AnastasiaKovaleva  See edit. I think you just explained this in last comment. What is the correct placement of everything?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var x = [[String: String]]()

    func loadData1(onCompletion: @escaping ([[String: String]]) -> ())
    {
        //do your stuff here and assume you get your data
        let data = [["key": "str"]]
        //then call completion callback
        onCompletion(data)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadData1(onCompletion: { json in
            self.x = json
            print(self.x)
        })

        //if you print here can not make sure you finished loadData1() because it is a async call.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the closure you are trying to use is operating in an async function (which you could guess by the parameter name `onCompletion`). This means that `print(x)` executes before your completion handler is called, so the value of `json` hasn't yet been assigned. For a very quick fix, you could move `print(x)` inside.

```
loadData1(onCompletion: { (json) in
    self.x = json
    print(self.x) // Now you guaranteed to have the value assigned to x before printing
})
```